# Getting feature names from a pipeline with tfidfvectorizer

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-extraction, tfidfvectorizer

I have been trying to get the feature names on my model for quite some time now but have a hard time understanding how to do it. I have tried many posts on here but can't get it to work. Here is my code:

*loading the classes I need to combine tfidfvectorizer with other features*

```
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator

class ItemSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key

    def fit(self, x, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, data_dict):
        return data_dict[self.key]

class FeatureTypeSelector(TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator):

    FEATURE_TYPES = {
        'categorical': [
            'COLUMN_A','COLUMN_B'
        ],
        'continuous': [
             'COLULMN_C','COLUMN_D'
        ]
    }

    def __init__(self, feature_type):
        self.columns = self.FEATURE_TYPES[feature_type]

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        return X[self.columns]


class RowToDictTransformer(TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator):

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        return (row[1] for row in X.iterrows())
```

*Then the code to put everything in a pipeline and run the regressor*

```
from sklearn.pipeline import make_union, make_pipeline
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
from sklearn.preprocessing import RobustScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

# Create the preprocessor
preprocessor = make_union(
    make_pipeline(      
        ItemSelector(key='TEXT_COLUMN'),
        TfidfVectorizer(lowercase=False, min_df=1),
    ),
    make_pipeline(
        FeatureTypeSelector('continuous'),
        MinMaxScaler(),
    ),
    make_pipeline(
        FeatureTypeSelector('categorical'),
        RowToDictTransformer(),
        DictVectorizer(sparse=False),  # set sparse=True if you get MemoryError
    ),
)

# fit and transform the data
preprocessor.fit_transform(x_train)

# choose some estimator
# estimator = MultinomialNB()
estimator = LinearRegression()

# Create the model
model = make_pipeline(preprocessor, estimator)

# Training the model
model.fit(x_train, y_train)

# Predicting the model
predicted = model.predict(x_test)
```

I can run the model.coef_ to get all the coefficients but I want to see how each item of the TEXT_COLUMN is affected by which weight. I have tried calling get_feature_names() or tried passing them in the pipeline but with no succes (most of google's results are purple by now).

Anyone that can give me a bit of guidance how to pass the feature names to the end of the pipeline? The ideal result would be a dataframe with the feature (row from the TEXT_COLUMN) and feature_weight as value.

Comment: You want to return a dataframe with `TfidfVectorizer` weights under their feature names?

Comment: exactly. The TfidfVectorizer will vectorize every word from the text column. When I run a linear regressor I can call the coefficients (an array of many values) but I can't call the get_feature_names() since it will provide the error:

`AttributeError: Transformer pipeline-1 (type Pipeline) does not provide get_feature_names.`

Comment: @DanielH. - By any chance did you get the answer to this question?